# Coded UI Tests on a lab environment

Tags: testing, tfs, automated-tests

I'm trying to set up a an automated build process and together with some coded ui tests. I think I've managed to set up pretty much everything up and working, the last missing piece of the puzzle being able to run the coded UI tests on the test agent machine.

So basically, I have a CI build that also runs unit tests, and if successful, deploys the binaries on a shared location. My goal is to then trigger the other process that runs the coded UI tests. I got the coded UI tests working on my dev computer by hard coding the location to start the application from. However, I am at a loss on how to configure this to work on the test agent. I used the LabDefaultTemplate11 build process template, and configured it to use the latest build completed by the CI build. But how do I specify what executable the test agent should use?

At first I thought it was enough to specify the build definition and build configuration, but then I realized there might be multiple executables, so the test agent would have to guess. Doesn't sound too good.

So in the end I guess my question is, how to (robustly) add the startup of the application to my coded UI tests in a manner that works both on my local dev machine, and the machine running the test agent?

Oh and I'm using TFS 2012 (with VS 2012 premium).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lab template expects you to create Test Cases in MTM then associated coded ui tests to them in visual studio by opening the test case, selecting the associated automation tab and clicking the "..." button.  You need to have the project with the coded ui tests open at the time.

Then in the lab build you select one or more Test Suite (from MTM) that contains the Test Cases for those coded uit tests.

When you make your tests in the first place make sure you're running your program/website in a way that the test agent will be able to also - eg use a standard installation directory or domain.

It is best practice to open the program being tested at the start of every test and close it at the end.  However you could get around that by executing the program as part of the deploy instructions in the lab build.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the test cases automated already, but the problem I have is with the startup of the app. Basically, I now created a deploy script that just copies the app from a shared network location, and I can then use this known location. This works with the test agent, but now I can't just run the tests from VS because the directory doesn't exist. So the main question is how to code the startup in a way that supports both from running from VS and from the test agent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776774/vs-2010-coded-ui-test-launch-referenced-application looks relevant